# Skype: Changing contacts display pictures

Tags: skype, contacts

Is it possible to for me to change my contacts display pictures in Skype (v. 5.1.0.112).

It could be nice to be able to set a display picture on my fixed-lined contacts - they all show up as a old-style phone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not available right now. You can only hide images in the contact list and in the chat, but not change it.

No extra too, as far as I know.

(Previously linked Skype forum page is no longer available)

Comment: Thanks! I'll just have to wait until they implement it then! :-)

Comment: Looks like the link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an iMac  you can open your address book and change the picture there than the picture in Skype will update as well.